# Adding environment variables in Ant build.properties

Tags: java, ant

Is it possible to use `$XXX_HOME` style variables in a `build.properties` file?

I set path of variable in `build.properties` like this

```
ant.home=/opt/java/myanthome
```

I have a `$ANT_HOME` environment variable with the correct path. Can I use this environment variable to set my `ant.home` in b`uild.properties`? I tried to add this in build.xml

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property file="build.properties" />
```

and in the `build.properties` file:

```
ant.home=${env.ANT_HOME}
```

but this does not work,it says:

> `${env.ANT_HOME}` does not exist

Comment: Are you running from an environment (such as an IDE) that does not already have `ant.home` defined?

Comment: I am calling ant script from java web service.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but there is no sense in doing it.

You can add a [`filter`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html) that pre-processes your property file. Consider the following property file:

```
ant.home=@ANT_HOME@
```

Then, you can filter it and load the file into properties, like this:

```xml
<filter token="ANT_HOME" value="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
<copy file="build.properties" tofile="build.properties.filtered" filtering="true" />
<property file="build.properties.filtered" />
```

The filter task, in addition with `filtering=true`, will replace the `@ANT_HOME@` token by the value of `${env.ANT_HOME}`.

But after having done all this, the question is, why filter the property file to begin with? You can just remove the `ant.home` property from your file and directly use `${env.ANT_HOME}` where necessary.